# ajax call to retrieve JSON using php proxy fails at %20

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a small problem.  I'm sending an AJAX call to retrieve JSON using a php proxy hosted on my website.  It's working great, but whenever there's an argument with a space, it gets encoded as %20 and I get back:

`{"status":{"http_code":400},"contents":"<html><body><h1>400 Bad request<\/h1>\nYour browser sent an invalid request.\n<\/body><\/html>\n\n"}`

How else can I encode the space to make this work?  Here's an example of the bad request URL.  The space appears in the city name "Santa Monica":

`http://www.mysite.com/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.eventbrite.com%2Fjson%2Fevent_search%3Fcity%3DSanta%20Monica%26region%3DCA%26country%3DUS%26within%3D15%26within_unit%3DM%26start%3D2013-12-10%26max%3D50`

EDIT:  AJAX request here:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url:'http://www.mysite.com/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.eventbrite.com%2Fjson%2Fevent_search%3Fcity%3DSanta%20Monica%26region%3DCA%26country%3DUS%26within%3D15%26within_unit%3DM%26start%3D2013-12-10%26max%3D50',
   dataType: "json",
   success: jsonFunction,
   error: jsonFunction
});
```

Comment: Lets see your AJAX request?

Comment: Spaces in urls should be encoded as `+`, not `%20`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I tried replacing %20 with + and got the same '400 Bad request' message

Comment: Ok, so I replaced with + and then encoded it to %2B to get it to work.  Thanks @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to encode the data yourself in the URL.  Let jQuery do it for you.

```
var search = {
   city: 'Santa Monica',
   region: 'CA',
   country: 'US',
   within: 15,
   within_unit: 'M',
   start: '2013-12-10',
   max: 50
};
var url = 'https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?'+$.param(search);

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url:'http://www.mysite.com/ba-simple-proxy.php',
   data: {
      url: url
   },
   dataType: "json",
   success: jsonFunction,
   error: jsonFunction
});
```

Comment: Nah, I'm just a web developer sitting in his office... or am I?  Anyway, glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 0):

you can use urldecode() function it will help you