# ajax error using proxy and jsonp, suspect is url alteration

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, jsonp

Not getting the content i want in an ajax function (first timer) which seems to be because the url is getting changed by the time it is sent, im not sure why or by what part of the functionality:
The ajax function uses a proxy.php on my domain to avoid Cross-Origin Request Blocked error. fyi this is in a wordpress site. The content of my proxy.php is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$json=file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
echo $url; ?>
```

The `echo $url;` at the end is there for testing - to see what is happening to the url address.

The proxy function and targeted url address:

```
<button id="srch">Search</button>

<script>
$("#srch").click(function(){
  var url= 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=6&gsrsearch=%22stones%22&gsrlimit=20&gsroffset=20&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json&callback=?';
  var urlbackend = '../proxy.php?url='+url;
  $.ajax({
    url: urlbackend,
    data: { url: url },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success:  function () {
      alert ("success");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

notice that the target: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=6&gsrsearch=%22stones%22&gsrlimit=20&gsroffset=20&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json&callback=? works in a broswer and produces the json i want But, the ajax fails (the alert and the console.log dont fire).

After clicking the button that fires the function  firebug console shows `GET` request to the following address:
http://www.mysitename.com/proxy.php?url=https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&&callback=jQuery11110023817249378105143_1408472896266&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fw%2Fapi.php%3Faction%3Dquery%26%23038%3Bgenerator%3Dsearch%26%23038%3Bgsrnamespace%3D6%26%23038%3Bgsrsearch%3D%2522stones%2522%26%23038%3Bgsrlimit%3D20%26%23038%3Bgsroffset%3D20%26%23038%3Bprop%3Dimageinfo%26%23038%3Biiprop%3Durl%26%23038%3Bformat%3Djson%26%23038%3Bcallback%3D%3F&_=1408472896267

and the response it gets is a default html message by wikimedia for failed api requests that has the echo $url i put in the proxy.php after the closing `</script>` tag. the url echos:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=6&gsrsearch=%22stones%22&gsrlimit=20&gsroffset=20&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json&callback=?

Which is also different from my original target url and incorrect.
What is causing these changes and how do i fix them? 
why am i geting this `&&callback=jQuery11110023817249378105143_140847289626` in the `GET` url?

Comment: Found an answer to the problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503244/ajax-call-to-retrieve-json-using-php-proxy-fails-at-20

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running through a proxy PHP file, you don't need to use JSONP as it is loading from the same domain.

You also need to [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) the `url` so that it is URL encoded, as your value contains a querystring. Without encoding these attributes are passed to `proxy.php` under their own key (`action=query` for example) instead of including this as part of the `url` parameter that is used to query the remote source.

```
var urlbackend = '../proxy.php?url=' + escape(url);
```

The use of `jQuery.click()` has been deprecated in favor of `jQuery.on('click')`.

Working code:

```
$("#srch").on('click',function(){
    var url= 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=6&gsrsearch=%22stones%22&gsrlimit=20&gsroffset=20&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json';
    var urlbackend = '../proxy.php?url='+escape(url);
    $.ajax({
        url: urlbackend,
        data: { url: url },
        success: function(response) {
          alert("success");
          console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: great idea and for sure step in the right direction but still giving me a non-functioning url. Think i should retry by separating the querystrings from the url?

Comment: I took a closer look and you actually have a few issues. If you are going to run it through a proxy, then you don't need to use `JSONP` since it's the same domain. I'll update the answer with some working code I tested.

Comment: great point on no need for `jsonp`. Was still getting bad urls. found an answear here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503244/ajax-call-to-retrieve-json-using-php-proxy-fails-at-20